# PHP: phpinfo function gives "no value" for some fields

Tags: php-ini, php

I recently went to some hosting provider website, registered and so on.

At one moment, I tried to run some functions, with no result at the end.

Then I decided to see phpinfo() page, and I have noticed, that, in certain fields,

there is declared as:

---

> no value

---

In this case, I was interesed in value of:

**

> disable_functions : no value

**

Does that mean, that there is really not declared what functions are disabled, or that field is not showing any value as it is managed to not show value in server configuration?

In example:

Functions like shell_exec, fopen and so on are disabled, but server is configured that way to not show me that? Or it really does not have any value?

Answer (score 1):

`no value` means `php.ini` contains no value for that directive. The user who is running the server or php process are disabled to run those functions (shell_exec, fopen) or system calls that those functions invoke.